# encode, decode base64 image stream delphi

Tags: image, delphi, stream, decode, encode

I'm trying to encode a stream of image using EncodeBase64 in encddecd.pass that save to the database in a blob field. And retrieve this using decodebase64 in a bytestream that put into a component for showing.
The process good done but image don't show in component.

Here's digest code:

```
procedure TProcessSave.Execute;
var
  i : Integer;
  fileStm : TStream;
  memStm : TMemoryStream;
  encode_plc : string;
begin
  for i := 0 to StrList.Count - 1 do
  begin
    DM.idb_tbl.Append;

    DM.idb_tbl.FieldByName('name').AsString := ExtractFileName(StrList.Strings[i]);  

try
  fileStm := TFileStream.Create(StrList.Strings[i], fmOpenReadWrite);

  memStm := TMemoryStream.Create;

  filestm.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);

  memStm.LoadFromStream(fileStm);

  DM.idb_tbl.FieldByName('file').Value := EncodeBase64(memStm.Memory, memStm.Size);

finally
  fileStm.Free;
  memStm.Free;
end;

DM.idb_tbl.Post;

end;
end;
```

and for loading:

```
procedure TLoadBar.Execute;
var
  imgStm : TStream;
begin
  with DM.idb_qry do
  begin
    DatabaseName := DM.idb_db.DatabaseName;

    SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM pics_tbl';
    Open;

   First;

   while not Eof do
   begin

     try

      imgStm :=TBytesStream.Create(DecodeBase64(FieldByName('file').Value));

      idx := imgBar_iemv.AppendImage;
      imgBar_iemv.SetImageFromStream(idx, imgStm);
      imgBar_iemv.ImageID[idx] := id;

    finally
      imgStm.Free;
    end;

  Next;
end;
end;
end;
```

and then I use imgStm for showing picture in a component but images not showing. I'm sure from component. What are your thoughts for encode and decode in my methods? Is another way that is sure for encode and decode for this problem?

Comment: You can't use `imgStm` for showing the picture, because your code creates `imgStm` and then immediately frees it. In addition, your code makes no attempt to display the image in anything at all, because it does nothing but create a `TBytesStream` and immediately dispose of it. You'll have to create a `TBitmap` or `TJpegImage` (depending on what kind of image was encoded), use it's `LoadFromStream` method, and  then assign that bitmap/JPEG to the `TImage.Picture` property.

Comment: You don't need intermediate streams. That's the whole raison d'etre of streams.

Comment: tanks for your answer i forget a portion of code to put here . in fact i use ImegeEn Component to show images . in this component exist a method that take an stream and show it.

Comment: I don't know what database you use, but you canusually just save an image as a binary to a text, memo, or blob field without any encoding.  Then you can simply read it back and save it to a file.

Comment: thanks for your answer i want to protect of stream that because i want to use encryption for stream this is very important for me.

Comment: If you want to encrpyt it, do that. Base64 encoding it is pointless.